# timelines of IC manufacturer company acquisitions/renames/spinoffs/etc.?

Tags: integrated-circuit, history

I'm wondering if there's any place out there on the 'Net that compiles information about semiconductor company acquisitions/renames/spinoffs/etc.

Just in the last 10 years, TI acquired National, Diodes Inc acquired Zetex, Maxim acquired Dallas Semiconductor, Agilent spun off Avago, and Tyco changed its name to TE.

(is this directly relevant to practical circuit design? no, but it has indirect usefulness for understanding history, esp. if you find old chip logos or datasheets.)

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question will be closed.

Comment: ho hum, another casualty of stackexchange strictness. :/

Comment: The biggest problem that I see with this question is that it simply could be answered with a single link (Assuming someone has this information). A single link does nothing to improve this site. What *could* be helpful is when you come across a time that a company acquisition/rename/etc has caused some confusion with a project you are working on and asking for the history of that specific case.

Comment: @Kellenjb How would that case be helpful and how would its solution be any different? Also I must express my disagreement with the statement:`A single link does nothing to improve this site.` It does! For example in [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/23375/1240) question a single link to datasheet for that component would help its OP and many other people who have problems finding info about that transistor. A single link is only unhelpful when it can easily be found. This obviously isn't the case.

Comment: @AndrejaKo What happens when/if that link becomes dead? Stackexchange is designed to be the source of information, not a database of links. There are times that linking to something can help supplement an answer, but the link should not be the primary source of info. The reasoning that a specific instance is more beneficial is that an answer can actually go into explaining the history and can provide some insight on things to watch out for when working with a specific legacy item. You can't possibly expect a single answer to do that for every single possible circumstance, thus being unhelpful.

Comment: nm, I'll just ask on reddit/ECE, where it would fit within their scope of operation.

Comment: While you are at it:  Wang Labs -> DEC -> Compaq -> HP -> ???. None known primarily as semiconductor companies (except perhaps HP) but all have had a part.

Comment: Leon needs to get a new default sentence :-)